# Strange ping behavior

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I built a linux distribution using the [Yocto Project](http://www.yoctoproject.org), with little customization. It runs on a Single Board Computer.

When I ping this machine, I get the following result:

```
PING 10.128.11.1 (10.128.11.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=9.79 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=7.76 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=5.78 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=3.75 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=1.80 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=99.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=8 ttl=64 time=97.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=9 ttl=64 time=95.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=10 ttl=64 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=11 ttl=64 time=91.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=12 ttl=64 time=89.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=13 ttl=64 time=87.8 ms
-- snip --
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=52 ttl=64 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=53 ttl=64 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=54 ttl=64 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=55 ttl=64 time=9.77 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=56 ttl=64 time=7.78 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=57 ttl=64 time=5.75 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=58 ttl=64 time=3.78 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=59 ttl=64 time=1.76 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.11.1: icmp_req=60 ttl=64 time=99.7 ms
```

The value keeps decreasing by 2 ms for each packet, then it goes up to 100 ms,
and decreases by 2ms again.

When I configure the interface, I get strange errors (but the interface works):

```
[   65.404850] irq 15: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[   65.404957] Pid: 661, comm: ifconfig Not tainted 3.8.1-yocto-standard #2
[   65.405036] Call Trace:
[   65.405136]  [<c10a9a39>] __report_bad_irq+0x29/0xd0
[   65.405237]  [<c13b18fd>] ? add_interrupt_randomness+0x1d/0x160
[   65.405329]  [<c10a9e65>] note_interrupt+0x165/0x1b0
-- snip --    
[   65.405617]  [<c112fcc3>] ? sys_ioctl+0x63/0x90
[   65.405617]  [<c1662970>] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
[   65.405617] handlers:
[   65.405617] [<c1473100>] rtl8139_interrupt
[   65.405617] Disabling IRQ #15
```

I searched for variables in `sysctl -A` output that could cause this behaviour, changed a few, but to no avail. I diabled IPv6. I tried a RT-kernel. I tried the kernel parameters `acpi=noirq` and `irqpoll`. I checked `dmesg` and saw that the driver registered the IRQ15 correctly:

```
[    6.926691] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
[    6.927813] 8139too 0000:00:09.0 eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x0001fc00, 00:05:b7:dd:53:25, IRQ 15
```

I have searched Documentation/ and Documentation/networking/ folders of the kernel for information, but found none. I used Google extensively, didn't find anything.

Any ideas of what might be the source of this behavior?

Comment: Some `ping` implementations use `gettimeofday(3)` to calculate round-trip times.  As a result, `ping` may print incorrect results if your system time is not reliable.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman Indeed, my `ping`
[implementation](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/iputils/3:20101006-1ubuntu1)
does use `gettimeofday`. However, I checked those results with Wireshark and it shows the same behavior (2 ms decrements). Therefore, I don't think `gettimeofday` is the culprit...

Comment: And, I think it might be worthy of note, those two computers are connected with a direct short Ethernet cable, so I would expect latencies in the order of _microseconds_, not _miliseconds_....

Comment: The `nobody cared` messages and the ping results are probably related. Is the `8139too` the right driver? In the past there been some issue with the `8139cp`. Have some option on insert? Some debug option maybe? On `/proc/interrupts` there's some other driver using 15?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a misconfigured BIOS. Resetting it to the default values solved the issue. I was not able to find which configuration caused the problem... I'm leaving this answer for the sake of completeness.